# how to disable keyboard for longpress android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have used a textbox to view text that is taken from string file. I want to give chance to copy text from the the edittext if users wishes. It can be copy fully or partialy.

when long press event is happend, copy message comes out. but vertual keyboard too comes out.
I can't hide it.
I have tried several way, here is my xml code.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="23dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:editable="false"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:inputType="none"
    android:padding="@dimen/padding_maintextview"
    android:text="@string/text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```

Here is the java code.

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(tvchange12.getWindowToken(), 0);
tvchange12.onCheckIsTextEditor();
```

Here is the MEdit class

```
public class MEditText extends EditText {
    public MEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCheckIsTextEditor() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

please help me to hide vertual keyboard for long press.

Comment: this is standard behavior. Better don't suppress it. Example - the user may want to select the text do delete or replace it, not only for copy.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to edit the text use TextView instead like this user can select and copy text without keyboard

Comment: textview supports for this from api 11. I use minimus sdk 8. therefore it wouldnt work